# Avoid Redundant Checking of Status from Method Response

Tags: dry

Basically, I have a controller method that calls methods from a service . I need to immediately return the response if the service call has failure status. The problem is that the checking of status and return statement gets too redundant especially on 5 or more method calls.

For example:

```
ApiController.cs

ApiMethod() {
    var response1 = _service.requestSomething1();
    if(response1.status == "Failure") { 
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response1); 
    }

    var response2 = _service.requestSomething2();
    if(response2 .status == "Failure") { 
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response2); 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement DRY principle here?